# Unable to edit my Wordpress website (through MAMP)

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, mamp

I downloaded MAMP and Wordpress and started creating my website. Later, when I tried to access my website to edit it, I found I could only view it and but don't know to get to the page where I can edit it.

I open MAMP and click 'Open WebStart page' and it opens the start up page.  Originally, I thought I was able to click 'My Website' at the top and it would take me to a page where I could edit it. Now it just takes me to a preview of the actual website.

I finally decided to just create a new WordPress page but when I watched a tutorial, I noticed the person clicked 'phpMyAdmin'. I don't have that as an option, my menu says 'Start, My Website, phpInfo, Tools, FAQ, Mamp Website.' So I'm very confused and can't even figure out how to start over. Any help would really be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As far as accessing phpMyAdmin you may have to go into your MAMP preferences, select PHP and then select 7.0 PHP version that will initialize the phpMyAdmin link. However that does not solve the dashboard problem.